Getting price in bulk-discount-rates.html in Big Commerce
Within Big Commerce, I'm trying to output some meta data for my bulk offers on particular products - in order to include the structured schema data. So I'm editing components/products/bulk-discount-rates.html in the template files (using 'Lifestyle'). But I can't seem to pass through the price from components/products/product-view.html. Originally I thought that I would be able to use it (within bulk-discount-rates.html) from the product like so:
{{product.price.with_tax.value}}

As can be done in product-view.html but seemingly not so. Therefore I tried to pass it through specifically, i.e.
{{> components/products/bulk-discount-rates product=product price=product.price}}

But this doesn't seem to be working as I can't get anything to output, e.g.
{{price.with_tax.value}}

Any help or insight is appreciated_
